# convert System.Byte[] to string or image format

Tags: javascript, c#

We have C# MVC model web app
blob data receiving from oracle and in integration following code is there

```
    foreach (DataRow oRow in oDataTable.Rows)
    {
    Rel oUnitData = new Rel();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oRow["LOG_SNAP"].ToString()))
    oUnitData.imgdisp = oRow["LOG_SNAP"].ToString();

     lUnitData.Add(oUnitData);
    }

    and for display using javascript file in that datatables 
    following part of code

    { data: 'imgdisp', "render": function (data) {

    var str = data
    var base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(str);
    return '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,+ base64_decode(str)+">';
    }

    Java Script Code 
------------------------------------------------

function LoadImageDispData() {

       var jsontext = JSON.stringify({
       });

       $.ajax({
           url: '/Rel_ProjectStatusUpdate.aspx/LoadImageDisp',
           data: jsontext,
           type: 'POST',
           async: true,
           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function (result) {

               if (result.d != null) {

                   oTableData = $("#tbl_imagedisp").dataTable().fnDestroy();

                   oTableData = $("#tbl_imagedisp").DataTable({
                       data: result.d,
                       responsive: true,
                       "bAutoWidth": true,
                       "bPaginate": true,
                       "bInfo": true,
                       "bFilter": true,

                       "aoColumns": [



                     { data: 'imgdisp', "render": function (data) {

                         var str = data

                         var base64string = Convert.ToBase64String(str);

                         alert(base64string);

                         return '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,+ base64_encode($str)+">';


                     }
                     }


                 ],

                       "columnDefs": [
                    { "visible": false, "targets": [] },
                { className: "dt-left", "targets": [] },
                { className: "dt-center", "targets": [] },
              { className: "dt-right", "targets": [] }
        ],

                       //"order": [[1, 'asc']],


                       dom: 'Bfrtip',
                       buttons: ['copy', 'excel'],

                       "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 75, -1], [25, 50, 75, "All"]],
                       "iDisplayLength": 25,
                       "bAutoWidth": true,
                       "language": {
                           //                  
                           //                    "zeroRecords": "Nothing found - sorry",
                           //                    "infoEmpty": "No records available"
                           "emptyTable": "No data available in table"

                       }


                   });

               }

               else {


               }

           }
       });

   }

Data Base Layer Code 
----------------------------------------
public DataTable GetImageDisp()
        {
            DataTable oDataTable = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteModel-Begin GetImageDisp");
                List<OracleParameter> lParameterList = new List<OracleParameter>();
                lParameterList.Add(new OracleParameter("O_IMGDATA", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
                oDataTable = this.GetDataTableREL("REL_GET_IMAGEDISP", lParameterList);


                if (oDataTable != null)
                    LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteModel-End GetImageDisp", string.Format("GetImageDisp Data Count:{0}", oDataTable.Rows.Count));
                else
                    LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteModel-End GetImageDisp", string.Format("GetImageDisp Data Count:null"));
            }
            catch (Exception oException)
            {
                LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteModel-Exception GetImageDisp", oException);
                ExceptionManager.LogSiteException(oException, "DrishtiCane.Model.WebSite.Implementation.WebSiteModel::GetImageDisp");
            }

            return oDataTable;
        }


Business Layer
--------------------------------

public List<Rel> GetImageDisp()
        {
            DataTable oDataTable = null;
            List<Rel> lUnitData = new List<Rel>();
            try
            {
                LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteIntegration-Begin GetImageDisp");
                oIWebSiteModel = this.ModelFactory.CreateObject<IWebSiteModel>();
                oDataTable = oIWebSiteModel.GetImageDisp();
                if (oDataTable != null)
                {
                    if (oDataTable.Rows != null && oDataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow oRow in oDataTable.Rows)
                        {
                            Rel oUnitData = new Rel();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oRow["LOG_SNAP"].ToString()))
                                oUnitData.imgdisp = oRow["LOG_SNAP"].ToString();


                            lUnitData.Add(oUnitData);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        lUnitData = null;
                }
                else
                    lUnitData = null;

                if (lUnitData != null)
                    LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteIntegration-End GetImageDisp", string.Format("GetImageDisp Data Count:{0}", lUnitData.Count));
                else
                    LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteIntegration-End GetImageDisp", string.Format("GetImageDisp Data Count:null"));

                // LoggingManager.LogDetails("End GetSubCMasterData", string.Format("Legend List Count:{0}", lVillageMasterList.Count));
            }
            catch (Exception oException)
            {
                LoggingManager.LogDetails("WebSiteIntegration-Exception GetImageDisp", oException);
                ExceptionManager.LogSiteException(oException, "DrishtiCane.Integration.WebSite.Implementation.WebSiteIntegration::GetImageDisp");
            }

            return lUnitData;
        }


Code Behind .aspx file
-----------------------------------------
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static List<Rel> LoadImageDisp()
        {
            List<Rel> lDatalist = new List<Rel>();
            try
            {
                IControlViewController oIControlViewController = oContollerFactory.CreateObject<IControlViewController>();
                lDatalist = oIControlViewController.GetImageDisp();
            }

            catch (Exception oException)
            {
                ExceptionManager.LogSiteException(oException, "DrishtiCane.SiteView.Report:LoadImageDisp");
            }

            return lDatalist;

        }
```

We have C# MVC model web app blob data receiving from oracle and in integration following code is there

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, I can't understand your code. And I'm not sure why you want to generate an img tag, rather than create an endpoint that can return the actual image.
However, one issue you have with your img tag is that it expects a string encoded in base 64 format, and I'm not sure what data type your "str" is.

Essentially, to create a base64 string in C#, the following can be used:

```
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data); 
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

You may need to include more information in your question for a better response.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited original question and added full code plz go through that.